# Mensagem "empurrou" a página para baixo, mas ao ser fechada a página não "subiu"

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, layout, notificações

Estava a editar uma pergunta, tive que me ausentar por um pedaço a meio da edição. Quando voltei, tinha um aviso de ponta a ponta da janela do navegador que havia nascido por cima do cabeçalho do site (menu) numa cor se não me falha vermelha/vermelho-acastanhada a dar-me conta que havia uma nova edição já aplicada no decorrer da que eu estava a realizar.

Cliquei no `x` para fechar e cancelei a edição (ou vice-versa), e o resultado foi:

[image: Captura de tela]

Ou seja, normalmente, o que vejo acontecer (com base em outras deste género que recebi) é que a notificação ao ser fechada, a página volta a "subir", mas neste caso em particular, tal não aconteceu tendo ficado o espaço da notificação em branco.

A pensar em várias coisas ao mesmo tempo não analisei o que se passava, tirei uma captura da tela, cliquei no <kbd>F5</kbd> e tudo ficou normal.

---

<sup>As minhas desculpas por um *report* tão vago, mas presumindo que se trata de um problema, uma simulação vai ser o suficiente para o evidenciar e fornecer uma base de análise.</sup>

Comment: Eu e o @bfavaretto fizemos um teste nessa pergunta, com as mesmas ciscunstâncias, e não conseguimos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @Gabe O problema remota a Março do presente ano, provavelmente já foi resolvido nalgum update ao sistema. De qualquer forma, desde que coloquei a pergunta até à data de hoje não tenho memória de ter acontecido novamente. `status-nãorepro` é o melhor para já :)

Comment: Pois é. O resultado do nosso teste foi bem diferente do seu, o que me leva a crer que esse alerta foi "refeito" para evitar este e outros problemas.